# Add custom tag in HTML mode in ace-editor

Tags: ace-editor

I'm using HTML parser in Ace Editor. I'm looking for a way to add a set of custom tags and set a colour for them.

Tags look like this: {%HEADER%}, {%CONTENT%}, {%FOOTER%}.

Example code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>{%HEADER%}<h1>
        {%CONTENT%}
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new highlight mode for ace. See https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/handlebars_highlight_rules.js for somewhat similar highlighter and http://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter for docs

Comment: Also have a mode for django https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/django.js#L87